# how to release kubelet pods space in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

Today my server disk running low, and i check the space and find the kubelet pod occupy too much,this is my check result:

```
[root@fat001 k8s]# duc ls -Fg /opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/
 22.8G 0c6d3318-3995-4337-8046-324efbca6926/ [++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]
843.9M 1f1ff85f-b1ea-44ad-81fe-2f2cb03a99f1/ [++++                                                                                                                            ]
424.9M cf8d2893-25aa-4583-9d7f-8c1844a74da4/ [++                                                                                                                              ]
288.7M 536d25c4-0f4a-4150-8066-d7f07499d470/ [+                                                                                                                               ]
145.0M a4854495-2b2e-4808-a2cd-7527fb401519/ [                                                                                                                                ]
143.4M 42392781-e52c-4454-8d07-14746b29d635/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 96.3M b3509742-03e0-46c1-afed-30d2148612ba/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 85.5M 8f99c52d-daea-4b41-b631-78cf7c15dd4f/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 74.7M 2f6c59a6-8225-45a3-ad3f-f199d4839244/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 68.4M 8b0a6798-98f1-45ed-b75c-eb36d48c90eb/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 61.7M f6de677c-5b19-4c8e-8c80-db289d4bb527/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 58.0M db14482a-0ae3-4e73-acc7-3b1f1c02c1c1/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 58.0M f07e621b-8a18-41ef-aa34-a082914e6abb/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 57.0M c0a14418-69c7-4a7e-9b63-d995a924621d/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 56.9M 80cce447-6a07-477d-82a7-6335344ebb04/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 56.8M d09d4b8d-e29d-4267-af9a-a8b37bd3487e/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 19.4M 84920357-6282-4fa2-813f-031e5600e6ce/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 19.4M be0d4f09-4c6a-4cc8-a245-273c8956302a/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 19.4M 2e6b53da-5b9e-46d4-b416-89b4611e6613/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 19.4M 2e6ec692-ab6a-4b1f-be17-bc97b1ccd129/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 19.4M fbc05da8-0ff7-4455-808f-2b5cdebb557c/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 68.0K acffc47c-f35e-4bb4-a1b8-648e7cb95b6b/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 68.0K 595af804-7855-4d73-bf66-72b9161f7966/ [                                                                                                                                ]
 48.0K 1cffcd44-56da-4809-832f-ba76c81b79b4/ [
```

I can find the the pod `0c6d3318-3995-4337-8046-324efbca6926` occupied 20GB+ disk size and total disk size is 40GB, so how to find which pod occupied and release the pod size? In my mind all pod should in the `/var/lib/docker/container` folder.

Comment: are these running containers or terminated?

Comment: I do not know , how to using the uuid to find the pods? I am searching in kubenetes dashboard with this uuid and find nothing. @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: It is very likely the UID of the Pod, as one can see from `kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] | {n: .metadata.name, u: .metadata.uid}'`

Comment: I enter into the directory and delele the `*.log` file.@OhHiMark

Comment: @Dolphin Could you please explain your actions in a form of an answer? It would be more clear and useful for the rest of the community with a similar problem.